# Bash script to check the group and permision

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am relatively new to the bash scripting

1. I want to achieve a bash script that ensures the file /test/file is owned by the group ‘test’ and has the group read and write permissions.
2. Update the bash script to allow an optional runtime parameter which ensures that anyone can list the contents of /test but only the owner and group can view and edit the files/directories within.

Comment: Can you give us a use case with examples?

Comment: Read `man stat;man -a chmod`. Your owner/group/world question is a classic Linux permission use case.

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Answer (score 2):

You can query all information of a file using the `stat` command. Consult `man stat`. You will see this allows you to granularly extract specific information such as owner and group using the `--format` option.

You can then change permissions and/or ownerships with `chmod`/`chown` according to your needs